# Including chmod in shell script - will it work for everyone?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix, chmod

I have a large `wrapper.sh` file which does a lot of things, but in the end runs `catalina.sh` tomcat.

Problem is that users who run this `wrapper.sh` are experiencing error: no permissions to execute `catalina.sh`. They have to manually set this permission, which is something I do not want.

---

On my computer, `chmod u+x catalina.sh` fixes this, therefore I included it in the `wrapper.sh`, right before executing `catalina.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# <...>
# <...>
chmod +x catalina.sh
exec ./catalina.sh
```

But will this change work for everyone? I can imagine, for example, that it indeed works fine on my computer, but someone else would get some sudo-related error when implicitly running that `chmod`. How can I make it work for everyone?

Comment: You already posted this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68063830/including-chmod-in-shell-script-will-it-work-for-everyone) (and it already has two answers). Please don't multipost, just pick the most appropriate forum, and ask there.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know about superuser forum before.